# Boolean Attributes Of Html

Tags: html, attributes, element

while I'm using html attributes, I saw boolean attributes and I have used it many times.

but when I went to mdn docs to boolean attributes I have read that Boolean attributes can only have one value, which is generally the same as the attribute name.

and also as we know boolean attributes can be written without a value.
but while I do some experiments I saw weird behave

```
<input type="text" disabled />
```

this is an input elemnet which has boolean attribute without value and it works correctly.

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

this is an input elemnet which has boolean attribute that has value of the same name as their name and it also as expected it works correctly.

```
<input type="text" disabled="anything" />
```

here an input element with boolean attribute which has value of anything and it works correctly.

why boolean attribute that has anything as value works correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes) for any questions of syntax. To quote it:

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> **The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.**
>
> Here is an example of a checkbox that is checked and disabled. The
> checked and disabled attributes are the boolean attributes.
>
> `<label><input type=checkbox checked name=cheese disabled> Cheese</label>`
>
> This could be equivalently written as this:
>
> `<label><input type=checkbox checked=checked name=cheese disabled=disabled> Cheese</label>`
>
> You can also mix styles; the
> following is still equivalent:
>
> `<label><input type='checkbox' checked name=cheese disabled=""> Cheese</label>`

Answer (score 0):

> why boolean attribute that has anything as value works correctly?

Browsers have *vast* numbers of error handling routines for recovering from invalid HTML.

That is one of them.